# DrupalKernel not found, after install package with composer

Tags: 8, composer

I have Drupal 8 Website and i want install this library with composer :

https://github.com/spatie/calendar-links

After run "composer require spatie/calendar-links", the drupal 8 make big error:

"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel' not found in /home/[...]/public_html/index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/[...]/public_html/index.php on line 16"

How can i resolve this problem ? I use composer with netbeans.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! In which directory did you execute Composer? Did you remove any Drupal file by mistake? Did you check none of the Drupal files is missing?

Comment: That said, you don't directly install a library on Drupal core, but you use a module that has the library as dependency. If there isn't any module that depends on that library, you create a custom module.

Comment: ok good i created i custom module and add class, but i don't know how i can pass variables to node.html.twig ?

Comment: Implement a preprocess function for nodes.